# Porque no se puede mostrar el contenido completo?

Tags: android, fragment

tengo puesto una serie de botones para mostrar un archivo PDF

Tendría que mostrar el pdf como aparece en esta captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se llega a mostrar completo como la imagen anterior, sino que se muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es la clase fragment que contiene el botón

```
    boton_documentos = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_docu_crevi);
    boton_documentos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmen_cre, new PDF_2(), "pdf 2");
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Este es el código que tengo en el xml que contiene el botón, no es que sea mucho código para mostrar solo un botón, tengo puestos mas botones.

```
RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmen_cre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_docu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:text="Documento"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**PDF_2.java**

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView  = inflater.inflate( R.layout.pdf_2, container, false );

        pdfView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pdf2View);
        pdfView.fromAsset("archivo.pdf").load();

        return rootView;

    }
```

**PDF_2.xml** donde muestro el documento PDF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.darwindeveloper.horizontalscrollmenu.PDF_2">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdf2View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

El codigo que para mostrar los dos pdf es el mismo, cambiando el codigo a donde apunta cada fragment, el PDF 1 a `android:id="@+id/fragmen_menu1"` y el DPF 2 a `android:id="@+id/fragmen_crevi"`

Situación de los botones en los diferentes Fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vídeo del comportamiento https://youtu.be/PEf2B2-z4Q4

¿Porque no se puede mostrar los PDFs como la primera captura?

Comment: Cual es el contenedor del PDF en el layout? Muestra el layout que carga el Fragment PDF_2 .

Comment: Hola @Elenasys ya he editado el primer post para añadir le código del PDF_2 con el que lo muestro

Comment: No corresponde el código con lo que muestra en la imagen, el contenedor FrameLayout  android:id="@+id/fragmen_cre" contiene los botones y cuando realizas la transacción para agregar el PDF debería reemplazar también los botones, asegura que es el código y layout correctos. @SoCu

Comment: @Elenasys en la imagen de esa captura solo he puesto el resultado final de como aparecen los PDFs, he añadido en el primer post una especie de esquema de donde se encuentran los botones, y un vídeo corto donde se ve el resultado